# groupby with column field having like column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using group by for like statement as i have database structure like this.

[image]

I want to get the count of workingzone groupby.but if i try to group by, then wrong output will appear as output will group by 99 and 99, as in figure.

[image]

My sql code is:

```
select count(organization),working_zone from `projects` where `district` = 12 and (`working_zone` = 99 or `working_zone` LIKE "99," or `working_zone` LIKE ",99") group by `organization`;
```

my desired result is:

---

### count |working_zone

### ____6| 99

### ____3| 100

(99),(,99),(99,) should be grouped by doing sum and result should be 6.

Comment: Have tried with `IN` caluse?

Comment: Do you have a separate table which contains the list of working_zone values?

Comment: But the best solution would be to redesign your table structure and have a separate table for storing id - working_zone pairs.

Comment: No, you cannot do this with an IN() clause.

Comment: i am doing reenginnering in this system so if i changed 1 table i have to change whole code..

Comment: Nevertheless, that would be the best solution. But I ask you again: do you have a separate table that lists all working_zone values?

Comment: Do you need these records row by row ?

Comment: I want the count result grouping by working_zone..

Comment: there is seperate table working_zones and it is linked with it, these value are bulk value of checkbox..

Answer (score 1):

You have an awful data structure -- although I wouldn't be surprised if the data is okay and you are really working off the result of a (reasonable) query.  You should not be storing raw data in comma-delimited lists.  Instead, use junction tables.

Why is having a separate row for each pair the SQLish way of storing data?  Consider these reasons:

- SQL has pretty based string functions (compared to other programming environments).
- Data should be stored in its native type; don't store numbers as strings.
- Foreign key relationships should be explicitly declared, and you can't declare a foreign key relationship using comma-delimited strings.
- The primary SQL mechanism for optimizing queries are indexes, and comma-delimited lists preclude the use of indexes.

Sometimes, though, you are stuck with someone else's bad design decisions.  If so, one solution uses a table of working zones:

```
select count(*), wz.working_zone
from projects p join
     working_zones wz
     on find_in_set(wz.working_zone, p.working_zone) > 0
where p.district; = 12 and
      find_in_set(99, p.working_zone) > 0
group by wz.working_zone;
```

Comment: @user2851129 Do you expect Gordon to read your mind? I cannot think of any other reason for not sharing what problem you have with his code! My guess is that when you look for working_zone 99, you also want to list the counts for all other working zones that are associated with working zone 99. Is this correct?

Comment: @user2851129 . . . Don't be shy.  Explain the problem.

Comment: yes i want to count all the possible (99) , (99,) and (,99) as same not differently

Comment: @user2851129 . . . This query should be doing that.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(organization),working_zone FROM table WHERE working_zone HAVING '99'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(organization),SUBSTRING(working_zone,4) FROM table WHERE working_zone = '99,100'
```